# Update / post database colum in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I have a general question.

I have a search form in larvel which returns results form the database.

in these i have an input field to enter a price if price  is == 0

what my problem is when i enter price and submit it returns to the search page without my previous search results i.e it doesn't refresh the same page with results and the newly updated field etc.

form in view

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'price_input'])->with($gyms) }}
                              {{ Form::text('enter_price', null, ['class' =>        'form-control', 'size' => '50', 'id' => 'enter_price', 'autocomplete' => 'on', 'runat' => 'server', 'required' => 'required', 'placeholder' => 'enter price!', 'style' => 'margin-bottom: 0px!important;']) }}
                             {{ Form::submit('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-   primary', 'style' => 'margin-left: 10px;']) }}
                        {{ Form::close() }}
```

route

```
 Route::post('/', [ //not used yet
'as' => 'price_input',
'uses' => 'PagesController@priceUpdate'
]);
```

Model

```
    public function priceUpdate($gyms)
{

    if (Input::has('enter_price'))
    {

    $price = Input::get('enter_price');
    Gym::updatePrice($price);

    return Redirect::back()->withInput();

    }


    Session::get('gyms');

    return Redirect::to('pages.home') ->with('gyms', $gym);   



}
```

not bothering with model as that works fine.

any ideas guys?

Thanks for your answer,

i have changed my controller to this

```
public function priceUpdate($gyms)
{



    if (Input::has('enter_price'))
    {

    $price = Input::get('enter_price');
    Gym::updatePrice($price);


    $gyms = Session::get('gyms');
    return Redirect::to('pages.home') ->with('gyms', $gyms);

    }




    $gyms = Session::get('gyms');
    return Redirect::to('pages.home') ->with('gyms', $gyms);
}
```

but when i run it i get 
     Missing argument 1 for PagesController::priceUpdate()
with the $gyms being passed into the method.

if i take out the $gyms that goes away but not sure if its still being passed with session or not, sorry im a novice.

orignally i had a search box which when run returns

```
return View::make('pages.home')->with($data);
```

what is the difference between that and

```
return View::make('pages.home')->with($data);
```

when i do the above line it returns to the search page with no search options from before update the form, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are just retrieving an existing session and doing nothing with it. You need to do:

```
$gyms = Session::get('gyms');
return Redirect::to('pages.home') ->with('gyms', $gyms);
```

Or

```
return Redirect::to('pages.home')->with('gyms', Session::get('gyms'));
```

Then you can access the gyms in the view with `$gyms`.

Alternatively, you could access `Session::get('gyms')` in the view as well.
Also, not sure if it's just the way you pasted it here, but you have an unnecessary space before the `->with`. Just wanted to make sure that's not part of the issue, too!